# .Filter() is not parsing correctly in my AngularJS web app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularfire

I get the following error on my Angularfire project when I try to add a .filter() to reverse the order of my array. When I don't include this .filter() in my code it works but the order of my array is in the opposite order of what I want.

I placed the filter code that I found on stack overflow [solution I found](http://plnkr.co/edit/REU7mTsfG5HISCnLKEr8?p=preview) in my App.js file

'use strict';

```
var app = angular.module('App', [
  'firebase',
  'angularfire.firebase',
  'angularfire.login',
  'simpleLoginTools',
  'slidesjs'
]);

app.filter('reverse', function() {
  return function(items) {
    return items.slice().reverse();
  };
});
```

It highlights that angular is not defined for the .module but even if without the filter code it still displays my messages so that may be a warning for something else.

The error I get in my console when I include the app.filter() code is

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: reverseFilterProvider <- reverseFilter
```

Comment: Are you trying to use your filter in a view or a controller?

Comment: Hey DuecePie! Welcome to SO. The code you've provided here does not reproduce the problem. Additionally, the details are extremely sparse. This appears to be using angularFire-seed or some variant, but no version or lib is mentioned. If I simply recreate your example here, take out the superfluous dependencies, that error does not exist. Please include an [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Cheers.